# Call a specific file with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm having a problem with ajax, so this is the original call from  My_Laravel_5/public/js/init.js

```
$('form#contactForm button.submit').click(function() {

  $('#image-loader').fadeIn();

  var contactName = $('#contactForm #contactName').val();
  var contactEmail = $('#contactForm #contactEmail').val();
  var contactSubject = $('#contactForm #contactSubject').val();
  var contactMessage = $('#contactForm #contactMessage').val();

  var data = 'contactName=' + contactName + '&contactEmail=' + contactEmail +
           '&contactSubject=' + contactSubject + '&contactMessage=' + contactMessage;

  $.ajax({

      type: "POST",
      url: "inc/sendEmail.php",
      data: data,
      success: function(msg) {

        // Message was sent
        if (msg == 'OK') {
           $('#image-loader').fadeOut();
           $('#message-warning').hide();
           $('#contactForm').fadeOut();
           $('#message-success').fadeIn();   
        }
        // There was an error
        else {
           $('#image-loader').fadeOut();
           $('#message-warning').html(msg);
            $('#message-warning').fadeIn();
        }

      }

  });
```

but I need to call another file wich is located in My_Laravel_5/app/Http/Controllers/sendEmail.php
I tried this:

- url:"../../app/Http/Controllers/sendEmail.php"
- url:"../app/Http/Controllers/sendEmail.php"
- url:"/app/Http/Controllers/sendEmail.php"

but this isn't working please Help.

Comment: You don't _call_ files, you load resources over HTTP. `sendEmail` being a controller it should have an associated route. You configured that route in `app/Http/routes.php` probably.

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel, you have a `app/Http/routes.php` file where you define the bindings between an url, the method of the request (get post delete...), and a controller method.

You should add to this file:

```
Route::post('/yourAjaxUrl', 'ControllerNamespace\ControllerClassName@method');
```

Where `ControllerNamespace` is the namespace of `sendEmail.php` and `ControllerClassName` is the name of the class you wrote in this file.

And then, in your `init.js`, change the url parameter of your ajax call object to `/yourAjaxUrl`

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your help but your solution isn't working, so I created my own contact form.